# Partitioning a set of integers into minimum contiguous subsets

Tags: number-theory

I am interested in the following problem: Let $A$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Partition $A$ into $m$ subsets $A_1, A_2, ..., A_m$ (i.e. $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i$) such that (i) $A_i$s are contiguous subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e., for every $i$, $A_i$ contains all the integers between $\min A_i$ and  $\max A_i$) and (ii) $A_i \cup A_j$ is not a contiguous subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (if $i \ne j$). That is to say, there exist an integer $k$ between $\min A_i \cup A_j$ and $\max A_i \cup A_j$ such that $k \not\in A_i \cup A_j$.

For example, if $A = \{1,2,5,6,10,11,12\}$ the $m = 3$, $A_1 = \{1,2\}$, $A_2 = \{5,6\}$, and $A_3 = \{10,11,12\}$.

I believe it is very easy to show that for every set $A$ such a partition exists and is unique (up to index permutations clearly). I was wondering if this problem is one of the classical problems in the set-theory or number-theory and has a well-known name or not.

More particularly, I am interested in the number of subsets in the partition $m$. I was wondering if this has a *standard* name?

Comment: So basically, you just want to split $A$ at its "gaps"?

Comment: Yes. Is "gap" a well-defined term in set theory?

Comment: Not really, although if you wanted to define them as "runs" and "gaps", people would probably understand what you were talking about. And I wouldn't call this a pure set theory problem, because the ordering of the positive integers is crucial in formulating it.